# Pass Java's Collections to C++ using JNA

Tags: java, c++, collections, jna

I researched thoroughly before posting this question. I am drawing a conclusion on JNA vs JNI. For this I really need to know:

**How can we pass java collection to c++ using JNA?**

Whenever I try to find out answers to this question I always get results with JNI. Please do let me know how this is handled with JNA. Is it through a callback mechanism or what?

Comment: With a few exceptions, it is not possible to map Java collections and data types in memory to something a C++ program would recognize. Presumably there will be a step inbetween to copy data from the Java collection into a native data structure and then pass the data structure.

Comment: can you please highlight those exceptions? and also in JNI, I saw we can callback method to get data from a list or map any idea about this strategy's counterpart in JNA?

Comment: I don't know what you found, but there is no such "callback". What typically happens is that you use JNI methods to extract Java objects from the collection and then convert these Java objects into regular C++ objects by reading fields with more JNI calls.

Answer (score 0):

JNA does not work directly with C++.  It uses `libffi` under the hood, which interfaces directly with a native C layer.  To deal with C++ code you need to `extern "C"` bits you need JNA to interface with.

Using a C-like interface, all Java to native data is passed as bytes.  In the case of collections, it will be multiple bytes back to back in contiguous memory as a C array.

If you have control of the DLL/native interface, you have two choices:

- Pass an actual (contiguous) array of the data
- Pass a (contiguous) array of pointers to the data which can be elsewhere.

In either case there is no mechanism to directly pass a `Collection` from Java.  You would have to do some sort of conversion to an array, either of the data itself, or pointers to it.

If you don't have control of the API, then that API already defines how you must pass the collection.